# How to parse Data from db.json file into the server?

Tags: javascript, json

First, I install **faker js** for using fake data into my projects.
Then I module code Into the **index.json** file like this

```
let fs = require('fs')
let faker = require('faker')
```

After that, I received data from **faker.js**, here is it

```
let arr = []

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    let obj = {}
    obj.name = faker.name.findName(),
    obj.email = faker.internet.email(),
    obj.phone = faker.phone.phoneNumber()

    arr.push(obj)

}

fs.writeFileSync('db.json', JSON.stringify(arr), function (err, data) {
    console.log('you recive data from faker js');
})
```

and it is created **db.json** file when I load this code

now I want to **parse** data into the server from **db.json** file.

***How Can I do that?***

Comment: What have you done in order to parse the data? What is the problem?

Comment: i want to do it like that. but its showing error                                                                                                                           
let data = fs('db.json')
let res = JSON.parse(data)
console.log(res);

Comment: how can i solve this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick:

```
let parsed = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('db.json'));
```

Comment: it's working. I want to something more from you. For examples, if I want to send single data like the only name into the server, can I do that?

Comment: You are getting an array of 10 names. If you want to refer to an entry in the array, just refer to it by index (0 - 9)  and then the name of the property (name, internet or phone. Example "console.log(parsed[4].name)" or "console.log(parsed[4].internet)"

Comment: Glad to help, if this answers your question be sure to mark it as answered.

Comment: i marked it you also please vote my qeustion if you like it